# Multiply line of textfile with value from list

Tags: python, list, text-files

I have a text file in the form of:

```
a, number, number
b, number, number
c, number, number
```

I want to multiply each line according to a list.
So for example if you have a list of:

list = [3, 1, 2]

The new text file should look like:

```
a, number, number
a, number, number
a, number, number
b, number, number
c, number, number
c, number, number
```

I read the file according to:

```
file = open("sort.txt", 'r')
f1 = file.readlines()
for line in f1:
```

Comment: Don't use `list` as variable name, because it will overwrite `list` builtin! And, welcome to SO :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

data.txt:

```
a, number, number
b, number, number
c, number, number
```

Code:

```
in_list = [3,1,2]
with open('data.txt', 'r')as fin, open('out.txt', 'w') as fout:
    for ind, line in enumerate(fin):
        lines = line * in_list[ind]
        fout.write(lines)
```

out.txt:

```
a, number, number
a, number, number
a, number, number
b, number, number
c, number, number
c, number, number
```

Comment: Looks good! I would use zip here instead your loop: `zip(fin, in_list)`.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Works perfectly.